# Json_encode user input (php code) without eval?

Tags: php

I want to return a json_encoded string from a form input like this

```
<input name="test" value="array(1,2,3)">
```

php should return: `[1,2,3]`

I can achieve it with eval doing : `eval("\$str=json_encode($test);");`

but then running eval on user input sounds like asking for trouble.

any other options?

Comment: Can you give some more context as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to do a json_encode online tool...

Comment: Why not just echo json_encode($test); ?

Comment: cause the form input is a string therefore it would output "array(1,2,3)" just as if I called json_encode("array(1,2,3)") instead of json_encode(array(1,2,3)). which is why I'm led to eval

Comment: send a serialize array, and `unserialize` at backend to get array

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to run PHP code from string without using `eval`

```
function fakeEval($phpCode) {
   $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "fakeEval");
   $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
   fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
   fclose($handle);
   include $tmpfname;
   unlink($tmpfname);
   return get_defined_vars();
}

extract(fakeEval('$test='. $_POST['test'].';'));
$json = json_encode($test);
```

[Source](http://gonzalo123.com/2012/03/12/how-to-use-eval-without-using-eval-in-php/)

Comment: If I'm not missing something, this one is just as insecure as eval for processing user input. Not to mention this won't work on windows due to absence of /tmp directory. Maybe you cound explain how is this any better from native eval function?

Comment: yes you are right, its insecure you will required to create some blacklisting for keyword to protect, same thing can be achieved with `eval` but some hosting provider disabled eval, you can use it there

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to create the inputs as an array for PHP to process:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

HTML

```
<input name="test[]" value="1" />
<input name="test[]" value="2" />
<input name="test[]" value="3" />
```

PHP

```
<?php

$test = $_POST['test'];
$jsonTest = json_encode($test);
// ...
```